# Trouble With Java getResourceAsStream, confusion with how Packages work

Tags: java, resources, lwjgl

I'm revisiting Java after briefly learning it in high school to work through the [lwjgl git book](https://ahbejarano.gitbook.io/lwjglgamedev/chapter4). There's a section that kind of loses me where the fragment shader / vertex shader is supposed to be loaded, using the function 'getResourceAsStream'.

I've tried different approaches, and vainly tried to debug / print the locations where the JVM was searching for the file, but I'm kind of at a loss. I am very confused, but would also prefer understanding why this code doesn't work on my machine, and how to get it to work (with this package / class loading approach).

Since the classes both share the 'main' class, I thought the JVM would search starting there for a 'resources' folder. But this does not seem to be the case.

I do think it has to do with the package declarations, but I don't understand enough to proceed.

Here are the relevant files and locations... I tried to only include what I thought important.

```java
// project-root/src/main/java/org/lwjglb/engine/Utils.java

package main.java.org.lwjglb.engine;
// other imports...
public class Utils {
    public static String loadResource(String fileName) {
    InputStream in = class.forName(Utils.class.getName()).getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    // 'in' is null after this call
    // other code...
    }
}
```

```java
// project-root/src/main/java/org/lwjglb/game/Renderer.java

import main.java.org.lwjgl.engine.Utils;
// other imports...
public class Renderer {
    public void init() {
        Utils.loadResource("/vertex.vs"); // fails
    }
}
```

```java
// project-root/src/main/resources/vertex.vs

// vertex shader code...
```

The issue is that the getResourceAsStream() call returns null, so the following code that depends on a valid result crashes with a java.lang.NullPointerException.

What path should I pass in to getResourceAsStream() so that it will not return null?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following directory structure:

```
|-- src
    `-- test
        |-- java
        |   `-- shaders
        |       `-- ShaderParser.java
        `-- resources
            `-- shaders
                `-- fragmentShader.txt
```

The proper way to get the resource "fragmentShader.txt" from "ShaderParser.java" is:

```java
Class clazz = Class.forName(TestUtils.class.getName());
InputStream in = clazz.getResourceAsStream("../../resources/shaders/fragmentShader.txt");
```

The `../` means "traverse upward one directory".
The path starts in the `src/test/java/shaders/` directory so we use `../../` to traverse upward twice into `src/test/` and then tack on the rest of our path `resources/shaders/fragmentShader.txt`.

It is important to remember that when using Class#getResourceAsStream(), it uses the package that the class resides in as the base directory. It **ONLY** uses relative paths because it is trying to load the resource using that class' [ClassLoader](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders). and will not work if supplied with a fully qualified path or a path starting at the project root.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) for more information.

Comment: In this case I'm not trying to pass a filepath that is relative to the current package, given that the packages were the java classes reside, a relative path would be obnoxious to read.

I added an answer explaining what I was looking for, and what I found as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had erroneusly thought that Java had a reserved directory (e.g. 'resources') where it would look first to load files. Kind of similar to Flask in python.

However, I understand now that the class.getResourceAsStream() function either takes relative paths (to the current 'lowest' level package) or absolute paths (from the project's top-level root).

I had furthermore erroneously thought that I could try doing a relative path load, from one of the higher-level packages. As in, I'm in package main.java.org.lwjgl.engine.Utils, but when looking for the file main.resources.vertex.vs, I could start the search from the 'main' package and pass 'resources/vertex.vs' or 'resources/vertex.vs'. I don't know if this is possible, but it feels erroneous.

Instead, the solution is to pass the file location '/main/resources/vertex.vs'. This will start at the project-root, and correctly load the file.

I'm still confused as to how the [lwjgl code](https://github.com/lwjglgamedev/lwjglbook/tree/master/chapter04) worked, but I see that it could be possible that the classPath was set to 'main', so passing an absolute path could work.